# Are there any limitations for an EU citizen immigrating to Andorra, since it is not in the EU?

Tags: immigration, eu, eu-citizens, residency, andorra

I like the nature and the tax scheme, but if I want to live there for longer than three months, it looks like there are some complications. I've read that I need to make a 15,000 investment and they only accept 900 new residents per year. However, this was only in one article, so I don't know if it's true.

So my question is, is it as simple as countries in the EU, where you can just go and stay if you have money or online employment as an EU citizen? Is there a way to immigrate without paying the investment? I will start a business, but I am not rich yet.

Comment: See: [Legislative decree of 6-2-2019 publishing the revised text of Law 9/2012, of 31 May, amending the Qualified Immigration Law. - Official Gazette of the Principality of Andorra.](https://www.bopa.ad/bopa/031013/Pagines/GL20190207_13_43_37.aspx) (in Catalan, Google Translate brings readable results)